# Ambiguous overloaded generic method with wildcard in parameter

Tags: java, generics, overloading, overload-resolution

Given the following declarations

```
interface Base<A> { }

interface Special<A,B> extends Base<A> { }

<T> void foo(Base<T> b) {}

<T> void foo(Special<?,T> s) {}
```

Why do I get a compile error for the following code:

```
Special<String, Integer> s = null;
foo(s); // error: reference to foo is ambiguous
```

BTW, the problem can be fixed by changing the declaration of the second method to

```
<T,X> void foo(Special<X,T> s) {}
```

Comment: PS: Yes, there are many questions about ambiguous overloaded generic methods, but I couldn't find one for this problem

Comment: This can also be fixed with `<T> void foo(Special<Object,T> s) {}`.

Comment: @sp00m Fixed, except that I could no longer call the second method with a `Special<String, Integer>`. The call would the unambiguously refer to the `Base` version.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a very interesting question.

#### Without generics

Consider the following code:

```
interface NoGenericsBase { }

interface NoGenericsSpecial extends NoGenericsBase { }

interface NoGenericsSuperSpecial extends NoGenericsSpecial { }

void foo(NoGenericsBase b) {
    System.out.println("Feel tha base");
}

void foo(NoGenericsSpecial s) {
    System.out.println("Special delivery");
}
```

We've always been taught that the compiler picks the *most specific method*. And indeed, the abovementioned code will, provided you call `foo((NoGenericsSuperSpecial) null)`, print the following:

> Special delivery

So far, so good.

#### Generics

Now, let's test some generics behaviour:

```
interface Base<T> { }

interface Special<T> extends Base<T> { }

void foo(Base<? extends Number> b) {
    System.out.println("Feel tha base");
}

void foo(Special<? extends Number> s) {
    System.out.println("Special delivery");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Special<Integer> v = null;
    new Main().foo(v);
}
```

This code compiles. The compiler finds two matches – both `Base<? extends Number>` as `Special<? extends Number>` apply –, but the compiler is able to figure out which is the most specific: it will pick `void foo(Special<? extends Number>)`, because both captures of the unbound wildcards are equal.

But let us rewrite `foo(Base<...>)` method and leave the remaining untouched:

```
void foo(Base<? extends Integer> b) {
    System.out.println("Feel tha base");
}
```

Now the following error occurs:

> reference to foo is ambiguous
>   both method `foo(Base<? extends Integer>)` and method `foo(Special<? extends Number>)` match

Before figuring out the most specific type matching, the compiler handles type variables. Apparently, **the compiler cannot figure out whether `<? extends Number>` or `<? extends Integer>` applies, unregarded the type of the variable itself** (`Base` or `Special`).

It seems that the variable type handling comes *prior to* the selection of method signatures regarding inheritance.

One (or at least I myself) should expect the compiler to pick `foo(Special<? extends Number>)`, but this is not the case.

#### The reason

I do not know whether the compiler is not able to pick the most specific one regarding generics, or it's not configured to do so.

See the Java Language Specification [§ 18.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5) or [§ 4.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) for more details.

*Let me take some time to read more of generics, so maybe we can figure it out...*